# AngularJS. How to pass model to the custom xeditable directive? (I'm trying to find the best way for updating model from ui-select)

Tags: angularjs, x-editable, ui-select

I have directive, that allow to integrate ui.select with xeditable. This is my directive:

```
var Dashboard = angular.module('Dashboard');

Dashboard.directive('editableUiSelect', ['editableDirectiveFactory', 'editableNgOptionsParser',
        function(editableDirectiveFactory, editableNgOptionsParser) {
            return editableDirectiveFactory({
                directiveName: 'editableUiSelect',
                inputTpl: '<span></span>',
                scope: {
                    eNgModel: "="
                },
                render: function() {
                    this.parent.render.call(this);
                    var parsed = editableNgOptionsParser(this.attrs.eNgOptions);
                    var filter = " | filter: $select.search";
                    var html = "<ui-select ng-model='eNgModel' theme='bootstrap' style='width: 150px'>"+ 
                        "<ui-select-match><span ng-bind='$select.selected.name'></span></ui-select-match>"+
                        "<ui-select-choices repeat='"+parsed.ngRepeat+filter+"'>"+"<span ng-bind='"+parsed.locals.displayFn+"'></span>"+
                        "</ui-select-choices></ui-select>";

                    this.inputEl.removeAttr('ng-model');
                    this.inputEl.removeAttr('ng-options');
                    this.inputEl.html(html);
                }
            });
        }]);
```

I want to pass model to my directive dynamically, but it seems, that xeditable `editableDirectiveFactory` not allow me to do this. As result, I can't save value, that I selected from this ui-select. What can I do for fixing this issue?

**SOLVED**(see my answer below), but my approach is just ugly workaround. I need somebody who can show me the best way of solving this problem.

Comment: I have a little progress. I replace `ng-model='eNgModel'` with `ng-model='"+this.name+"'` in my `html` variable and now when fields become editable, they contains current model value. But model still not save. I continue to debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I solved this problem by adding `setModel` method to `on-select` attribute of `ui-select`.
So, this way my `html` variable changed to:

```
var html = "<ui-select ng-model='"+this.name+"' theme='bootstrap' style='width: 150px' on-select='setModel($item)'>"+ 
                        "<ui-select-match><span ng-bind='$select.selected.name'></span></ui-select-match>"+
                        "<ui-select-choices repeat='"+parsed.ngRepeat+"'>"+"<span ng-bind='"+parsed.locals.displayFn+"'></span>"+
                        "</ui-select-choices></ui-select>";
```

Next, I just add to each controller `setModel` method. (I mean controllers, in which template I'm using this directive). Example of method:

```
$scope.setModel = function(item) {
                if (item.hasOwnProperty('property')) {
                    $scope.object1 = item;
                } else {
                    $scope.object2 = item;
                }
            }
```

And, finally, I just getting `$scope.objectX` value in my save method.

This approach is just ugly workaround, so I really need somebody, who can show me the best way.

Comment: you'll only have ugly workarounds when you are treating HTML as data and storing it in JavaScript variables, unfortunately.

Comment: @Claies Thanks for comment. I'm using sources of xeditable.js as example, this approach is used in its own directives. Unfortunately. But I think, that you are right, so in nearest time I'll try to move all html markup from js into separate .html file.